# C# WebApi POST creating a objects with complex json data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two models, a SettingCollection, and a SettingValue. A SettingCollection has many SettingValues. This is the setup of this relationship.

```
public class SettingCollection
{
    public int SettingCollectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SettingValue> SettingValues {get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    public class SettingValue
{
    public int SettingValueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
        
    public int SettingCollectionId { get; set; }
    public SettingCollection SettingCollection { get; set; }

}
```

To create a new SettingCollection and SettingValues in one call, I am POSTing the following payload:

```
    {
  "Name": "Company Collection",
  "Key": "company_collection",
  "Priority": 3,
    "SettingValues": 
    [{"Name": "Is this true", "Value": "True"}]
}
```

And my response is:

```
    System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32 maxDepth)
```

Is this just something I cannot do and will have to use NewtonSoft to suss out the raw data in the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These classes are self referenced, so they go into the loop. You can just ignore sub classes with `JsonIgnoreAttribute`. I used this with `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` and works fine.

```
public class SettingValue
{
   public int SettingValueId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public int SettingCollectionId { get; set; }
   
   [JsonIgnore]
   public SettingCollection SettingCollection { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This is what did it. I added that connection, as this was in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#definition-of-terms

Comment: I think you can create data transfer objects of these classes.They just can't be serialized because they are self referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Add this options to your newtonsoft.json in your startup file

```
  AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
                })
```

Comment: I have tried a few different iterations of this, but i keep getting unresolved symbol for AddNewtonsoftJson.

Comment: Make sure you add the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson from nuget package manager. try version 3.1.4

Comment: I have 3.1.5 installed.

Comment: provide more information, is your code not compiling after you  add the nuget package. what is error message are you getting. unresolved symbol is pretty vague